# Bootstrap Vue Checkbox: How to check/uncheck checkbox when clicking another element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I read the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox/) yet I can't find any example of a bootstrap vue checkbox being set to check/unchecked when clicking a table row (when it is underneath a table). Is there a way that clicking a row will result to it being checked/unchecked?

```
data() {
  return {
    form: {
      optional: {} as { [index: string]: boolean },
    }, 
  };
},
methods: {
  triggerCheckBox(relatedId: string) {
    const val = this.form.optional[relatedId];
    this.form.optional[relatedId] = !val;
  },
}

<tr v-for="related in liability.related" @click="triggerCheckBox(related.id)">
  <td>
    <b-form-checkbox
      v-model="form.optional[related.id]"
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </td>
```

Edit: I already manipulated the v-model bind to the checkbox. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Typically, you'd just toggle the value that the checkbox is bound to (its `v-model`). What does your code look like?

Comment: Edited. I just didn't post the code because I assumed this is the default behavior of the checkbox on bootstrap vue where the changes on the model isn't 2 way binding which was confirmed on my code. I also notice that setting the default values to `true` doesn't set the checkbox to `checked`.

Comment: Adding new properties to your objects defined in `data()` (ie `this.form.optional[relatedId] = !val`) is not reactive. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 2):

I added this on my code on my created hook:

```
this.$set(this.form.optional, related.id, false));
```

to set the `form.optional` to reactive..

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you put the prop

```
value=true unchecked-value=false
v-model="varaible_of_your"
***"variable_of_your=true or false"
```